# How to return from a select with SIGINT

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select, signals

I need your help to solve this problem.
I have to create a multi-threaded client-server program on unix, based on AF_UNIX
sockets, that must handle up to some thousands simultaneous connections and also must do different things based on the type of signal received, like shutdown when server receives a `SIGINT`.

I thought of doing this disabling, initially, `SIGINT` and the other signals from the main's thread sigmask, then starting up a dispatching thread, that keeps (I know that's really inefficient this) waiting on `select()` for I/0 requests, accepts the new connection and then reads exactly `sizeof(request)` bytes, where `request` is a well-known structure, then creating also a thread that handles the signals received, the only one that re-enables the signals, using `sigwait()`, and finally starting up the other server thread to execute the real work.

I have this questions:

- I would like to let `select()` return even if the dispatcher thread is stuck in it. I've red of a *self-pipe trick* about this, but I think I made it wrong, because even if I let the signal-handling thread write in the pipe that's in the select's read set, `select()` won't return. How could I let `select()` return?
- I've read something about `epoll()`, that's the efficient to handle many simultaneous connections efficiently. Should i, and if how, use it? I can't figure it out only reading `man epoll`, and on my text book it's not even mentioned.
- There are some good practices that I could use for handling system's failures? I almost check every system call's return value to, eventually, handle the error to free memory and other stuff like this, but my code keeps growing a lot, and almost for the same operations repeated many times. How could I write a cleanup function that could free memory before returning with `abort()`?

Anyway, thanks a lot in advice for your help, this platform is really amazing, and when I'll get more expert, I'll pay the community back giving my help!

(Sorry for my English, but it's not my mother language)

Comment: There are probably high level libraries that already do it way better than any simple code will.

Comment: I think using a unix pipe to turn an a-synchronous event (signal) into a synchronous event is a valid way to handle this. `select` should return if the unix pipe is in the set of descriptors and becomes readable.

Comment: You are talking about thousands of connections; probably should not use `select` as it has an upper limit.on the descriptor integer value (and is inefficient for larger numbers). `poll` does not have an upper integer limit, but still does not scale well for a large number of descriptors. `epoll` scales better since it does not have to iterate over a set of active descriptors. Instead, the kernel reports which descriptor is active. `epoll` is a linux-only system call though

Comment: If this is on Linux, just use `signalfd`. (Signals are so annoying they added a way to avoid them completely!). Otherwise, the self-pipe trick *should* let `select` return.

Comment: I need to let  `select()` return for sure! Yeah, i'm on unix.
epool is interesting, but can someone give me a link with a full C example?